# Chart/ table to visualize how hot a device is actually getting

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, heat, heatsink, power-dissipation

Maybe my question will be a little funny. But it will be very helpful if you can give a little information about one thing. In electronics, we calculate power at various points/calculations to predict/understand how much a device will actually heat/ or how hot it is. , My question is. is there any chart or table? So that I can visualize how hot a device is actually getting.
[image]

Comment: How hot a device gets depends on many things such device package, airflow and ambient temperature (not just that at 25C ambient it will be 25C hotter than if it were 0C ambient. There is an equilibrium between the heat exchange since a larger temperature difference will exchange more heat which changes the equilibrium temperature that is reached over time). But you can get rough approximations for some scenarios using *dissipated* wattage (not supplied wattage) and package thermal resistance in the datasheet.

Comment: @DKNguyen one thing that I didnt anticipate is also the thermal mass. Some packages like die GaN transistors are so small that they need much better thermal transfer

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no, thre is no such general table or curve.

Longer answer:
How hot a device gets depends how much Power a device gets and how much it can dissipate. Assuming that input power is given (like in most cases) the temperature of the device depends on several factors.

The (steady state) temperature of a device is where the input power and dissapiated power are the same.

What factors are in play:

- ambient temperature (can also be the temperature within a case)
- heat resistance towards ambient
- how hot the semicunductor die can get without beeing degraded/destroyed

Both of those things can change, that's why you can't just draw a curve of power vs. temperature that matches everything.

What's heat resistance?
That's basically like electric resistance. Basically "how much power can be transfered with a given temperature difference".

Now I could try to explain how thermal resistance (or thermal conductance) works. But others have done this already, so I'll just link to a document that describes [Thermal Resistance](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/applinote/common/basics_of_thermal_resistance_and_heat_dissipation_an-e.pdf) quite nicely.

Basically it boils down to: Thermal Resistance depends on

- size of semiconductor inside case
- type of case
- how the case of the semiconductor is mounted (horizontally, vertivally, whatever)
- how long and thick the leads of the semiconductor are and what material they are made of
- how thick the traces are on the PCB
- if there is a heatsink attached and how it is attached and how well the case is mounted to the heatsink and what type and amount of thermal compund is used
- how the heatsink is mounted (vertical, horizontal)
- how much space there is around the heatsink
- if air is forced over the heatsink or if we rely on convection

As an example:

1. A Semiconductor in a TO-220 case at room temperature without heatsink mounted tanding on a PCB can disssapiate about 1-2W over prolonged periods of time. You'll burn your finger if you touch the case but it will work.
2. Same semiconductor  can dissapiate 50W and more with a good heatsink and forced cooling (probably even more, numbers just from the Top of my head)

There are some "rule of thumb" 'numbers around. but there are no finished tables and curves for a good reason.